# Check ng repeat list length in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using repeat for dynamically add or remove phone numbers. In this case I have separated `ng-repeat` content into separate file. I have included this separate file by using `ng-include`. All of works are working fine. But I want to get `ng-repeat` list length into separate file. This is my code

```
<div>Total Length: {{settings.contacts.length}}</div> --This is working

<div>Total Length: {{$parent.contacts.length}}</div> --But I need this type of work like as knockout js.
```

This code is containing into separateFile.html in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L5a5xUh5AkuXDF9wTchj?p=preview).

From two lines of above code, I need a second option that is look like as knockout js. Is it possible?

Comment: `$parent` what is it exactly in your case? do you want it from `$scope`?

Comment: Thanks @Jai for your reply. I do not want to write any code into controller. Without writing code into controller you can use everything.

Comment: @Sohel still you have not responded on the first question in my comment about `$parent`.

Comment: Why do you want it to look like knockout? `$parent.contacts.length` doesn't work because the only thing on the parent scope is `settings` (because you're using "controller as" syntax). So if you really really want to use `$parent`, you'd have to say `$parent.settings.contacts.length` (but you'd never do that because there's no need).

Comment: Hi @Jai, no need exact.

Comment: @AnthonyChu, I did not say that you have to use $parent. If any other option which will perform my task.

Comment: Given the conversation above, I think it might be worth putting this question on hold as "unclear" - it seems that readers did not understand it.